# Discards qualifiers with memcpy

Tags: c, c99

Why does the following code give me a "discards qualifiers" warning?

```
double* const a[7];
memcpy(a,b,sizeof(double*)*7);
```

The error I'm getting with Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn) is

```
warning: passing 'double *const [7]' to parameter of type 'void *' discards qualifiers
```

**Edit:**

Bonus question. Why does the restrict keyword not work either?

```
double* restrict a[7];
memcpy(a,b,sizeof(double*)*7);
```

**Edit 2:**

I'm asking this question, because I want `a` to be a `const restrict` pointer. I can get this result with this code:

```
double* const restrict a[7] = {b[0], b[2], ... b[7]};
```

Is that a stupid thing to do?

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to pass a const pointer to a function that expects a non const pointer.

Edit:

More specifically, `a` is an array whose contents are `const` pointers to doubles.  If you attempted to do `a[0] = b[0]` (assuming `b` is defined as `double *b[7]` or something similar) you would get a compiler error.  The results would be the same if you had `const char a[7]` and attempted `a[0] = 'x'`.

Calling `memcpy` as you are allows it to effectively perform the operation above which would otherwise be prohibited.

In the case of `restrict`, that tells the compiler that the memory pointed to by the given pointer will only be addressed by the given pointer.  This allows the compiler to perform certain optimizations.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict):

> It says that for the lifetime of the pointer, only it or a value
>   directly derived from it (such as pointer + 1) will be used to access
>   the object to which it points.

Since `memcpy` is not expecting a `restrict *` that guarantee is lost, which is why you get the warning.  In general, bypassing `restrict` like this can lead to unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Thanks. I see it now in the documentation. But why does memcpy expect a non-const pointer? Shouldn't it just copy something to the address and not do anything with the address itself?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question so much as reword the error message.

Comment: @hanno: History. C only gained `const` relatively recently.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's strange though that it has the `const` keyword in the second argument, the source (for the data, not the pointer). I still don't understand the logic.

Comment: @hanno: By its definition, `memcpy` writes to the destination location while only reading from the source location. Having `const` in the second parameter further emphasizes that.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev I don't see how this answers the question. The pointer to the destination could still be `const`.

Comment: The non-constness of the first parameter basically tells the caller that the called function (in this case `memcpy`) is allowed to go to the location where "destination" points to and then modify the bytes there. The const parameter, in contrast, forbids that to the function - it can only read what's there, but not modify it.

Comment: I think what you say would be true if it were `const void * const destination`.  But with `void * const destination`, I could still write to wherever `destination` is pointing, just not change the address, `destination`, itself.

Answer (score 3):

`memcpy` takes three arguments. The first argument is the place into which the data will be copied. Since the location pointed to by the pointer is going to be modified, whatever the pointer points to must *not* be constant in order to avoid potential undefined behavior.

Since you pass `a`, a `const` pointer, as the first parameter, you get a warning.

Note that the second parameter can point to a `const` location, because the data is read from it.

The signature of the function looks like this:

```
void* memcpy(void* dest, const void* src, size_t count);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `a` is const.

`double* const a[7];` is an array of 7 pointers to double. This array (!, not the doubles that are pointed to) is marked as const. memcpy's first parameter is the destination, which is not const (so it can be written to). So passing the const `a` as non-const destination to memcpy is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

In this call

```
memcpy(a,b,sizeof(double*)*7);
```

that could be written much simpler the following way

```
memcpy( a, b, sizeof( a ) );
```

function `memcpy` changes elements of array `a` because it copies elements of array `b` into elements of array `a`.

However the declaration of array `a` looks the following way

```
const T a[7];
```

where `T` can be defined like

```
typedef double * T;
```

That is you are trying to change a constant array and the compiler warns you about this operation that has undefined behaviour.

I suspect that maybe you mean another declaration of array a as for example

```
const double * a[7];
```

In this case you could use the call of function `memcpy`.

Comment: It's not. You don't get a warning for "trying to change a constant array". You get an error if it's through a `const` object, and nothing but UB otherwise. The warning is for an attempted implicit cast-away of `const`ness from the type.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit  Till now I thought that removing constness means that you are trying to change a constant object.:)